# NASM Specific -- Section vs [SECTION ]

Tags: assembly, nasm

I cannot seem to find anything clear in NASM's documentation regarding the difference between using Section or [SECTION ] (with the brackets) in your code. I am aware these are macros, but I see them used almost interchangeably. Is this the case? In other words is

```
[SECTION .text]
```

Equivalent to

```
Section .text
```

?

Do brackets maybe imply some arcane side effect?

Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`[SECTION .xyz]` is the primitive form of the section directive which simply sets the current output section, `SECTION .xyz` differs slightly because it works like a macro:

```
SECTION .text
```

expands to the two lines

```
%define __SECT__ [SECTION .text] 
[SECTION .text]
```

which can be used in conjunction with a macro to temporarily switch the output section, and switch it back to its original value.  Example [from the NASM manual](https://nasm.us/doc/nasmdoc7.html#section-7.3):

```
%macro  writefile 2+

[section .data]

%%str:        db      %2
%%endstr:

    __SECT__

    mov     dx,%%str
    mov     cx,%%endstr-%%str
    mov     bx,%1
    mov     ah,0x40
    int     0x21

%endmacro
```

When you use this macro, the output section is set to `.data` temporarily by the primitive form of `SECTION`, and set back to its original value with `__?SECT?__`