# Defining variables within a macro causes multiple definitions of the same variable

Tags: assembly, macros, nasm

```
%macro printhello 0
  section .rodata
  %%msg:  db  "Hello, world.", 10, 0
  section .text
       push  %%msg
       call  printf
       add   esp, 4
%endmacro
```

The problem is that every time the macro appears in the program, NASM preprocessor will invent a new name for the label `msg` and there will be multiple definitions of the same string `"Hello, world."` I could define the string without the `%%` prefix, but if the macro will be used more than once, I will get an assembly error for redefining the same symbol, `msg`. So how can I avoid multiple definitions of that string?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could do something like this:

```
%macro printhello 0
  %ifndef HelloWorldMsg
  %define HelloWorldMsg
  section .rodata
HWM:   db    "Hello, world.", 10, 0
  %endif
  section .text
       push  HWM
       call  printf
       add   esp, 4
%endmacro
```

Comment: Note that `section .text` will switch to the `.text` section even if that wasn't the section that was active at the point the macro was called, probably breaking the surrounding code.

Comment: You can switch back to the original section instead of unconditionally to `.text` as shown in https://nasm.us/doc/nasmdoc7.html#section-7.3 /  [NASM Specific -- Section vs \[SECTION \]](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5925797)

Comment: This include-guard idea to avoid repeated definition is a good one.  If you have *different* data for different instances of the macro, you can use `%%HWM:` and `push %%HWM` to get a label name unique to each expansion of the macro.

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure I see the point of putting "hello world" in the macro. I should think you'd want to pass the text to print as a parameter to the macro, no?

```
%macro printhello 1
section .rodata
%%msg:  db  %1, 10, 0
section .text
   push  %%msg
   call  printf
   add   esp, 4
%endmacro

section .text
_start ; (?)
printhello "hello world"
printhello "goodbye cruel world"
```

That's untested, but "something like that"...

Best,
Frank