# NASM - Macro local label as parameter to another macro

Tags: assembly, x86, macros, x86-64, nasm

I am trying to use a macro ([as shown in this tutorial](https://0xax.github.io/asm_5/)) to print a string. The macro `PRINT` creates local labels to define the string content (`str`) and length (`strlen`), and then passes these as parameters to a second macro `_syscall_write` which makes the syscall.

However running the code fails and I get a `Segmentation fault (core dumped)` message.

I suspect the problem to be this particular lines, but I don't understand why.

```
mov rsi, %1  ; str
mov rdx, %2  ; strln
```

Here is the full code:

```
%macro PRINT 1

    ; Save state
    push rax
    push rdi
    push rsi
    push rdx

    %%str    db  %1, 0       ; arg0 + null terminator
    %%strln  equ $ - %%str   ; current position - string start

    ; Write
    _syscall_write %%str, %%strln

    ; Restore state
    pop rdx
    pop rsi
    pop rdi
    pop rax

%endmacro

%macro _syscall_write 2
    mov rax, 1
    mov rdi, 1
    mov rsi, %1  ; str
    mov rdx, %2  ; strln
    syscall
%endmacro


global _start


section .data

    SYS_EXIT   equ 60
    EXIT_CODE  equ 0


section .text

    _start:

        PRINT "Hello World!"


    exit:

        mov rax, SYS_EXIT
        mov rdi, EXIT_CODE
        syscall
```

Here is a disassembly of the object file (from a version with the push/pop commented out).

Looking at the expanded code I still cannot see what is wrong. The bytes 0x0..0xC look like gibberish but correspond to the ascii code of the characters in `Hello World!`. Before the syscall to sys_write, `rax` and `rdi` seem to receive the expected value of `0x1`, `rsi` the value of `0x0` which points to the string start, and `rdx` the value of `0xd` which is the string length (12 + 1)...

```
Disassembly of section .text:

0000000000000000 <_start>:
   0:   48                      rex.W
   1:   65                      gs
   2:   6c                      ins    BYTE PTR es:[rdi],dx
   3:   6c                      ins    BYTE PTR es:[rdi],dx
   4:   6f                      outs   dx,DWORD PTR ds:[rsi]
   5:   20 57 6f                and    BYTE PTR [rdi+0x6f],dl
   8:   72 6c                   jb     76 <SYS_EXIT+0x3a>
   a:   64 21 00                and    DWORD PTR fs:[rax],eax

   d:   b8 01 00 00 00          mov    eax,0x1
  12:   bf 01 00 00 00          mov    edi,0x1
  17:   48 be 00 00 00 00 00    movabs rsi,0x0
  1e:   00 00 00
  21:   ba 0d 00 00 00          mov    edx,0xd
  26:   0f 05                   syscall

0000000000000028 <exit>:
  28:   b8 3c 00 00 00          mov    eax,0x3c
  2d:   bf 00 00 00 00          mov    edi,0x0
  32:   0f 05                   syscall
```

Comment: When troubleshooting macros always look at the expansions. When troubleshooting segfaults always use a debugger. One obvious problem is that you define your string in the code path so the cpu will try to execute it as instructions and that will likely fault. Use a different section, normally `.data` or `.rodata` for your string or at the very least make sure your code jumps around it.

Comment: @Jester How can I view the macro expansion? Edit: just remembered objdump

Comment: Use GDB's disassembly view to single-step through instructions, not source lines.  e.g. `layout reg`.  See the bottom of https://stackoverflow.com/tags/x86/info for debugging tips.

Comment: @PeterCordes Ah, though the expansion is what I expect it to be, 0x48 ('H') 0x65 ('e') etc. aren't valid instructions... The tutorial had a jump to the syscall before these local definitions, which I ignored but now I understand why it was there. Thanks!

Comment: Your machine code doesn't match your source.  Your macro uses 4x `push` instructions before the `db`, but your `objdump` starts with the string data.  Also, if you were trying to preserve all regs, you forgot RCX and R11 (clobbered by `syscall` itself.)

Comment: @PeterCordes When compiling I used the `-f elf64` flag, and when using objdump the `-M x86-64` flag with the goal of both being 64 bit...I'm not sure where/why the mismatch happens...Thanks for the heads up on the shortcoming of saving just the registers I directly use.

Comment: I added a section to my answer with my objdump output.  Yours appears to be broken somehow.

Comment: @PeterCordes Ah sorry, I realized the source of the discrepancy (facepalm)...I had the push and pop statements commented out in an attempt to narrow down the cause.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`rex.W gs ins` is a privileged instruction, and faults in user-space.  This is the first instruction of your program, from the expansion of `%%str    db  %1, 0` in your macro without changing sections.

**Don't put data where it will be executed as instructions; use `section .rodata` for read-only data,** (or `.rdata` on Windows) then switch back to the original section.

```
%macro PRINT 1
  ...
section .rodata 
    %%str    db  %1, 0       ; arg0 + null terminator
    %%strln  equ $ - %%str   ; current position - string start
section .text
  ... rest of the macro
```

**This unconditionally switches to the `.text` section**, regardless of what section you were in when you used this macro (e.g. `.text.cold` or some other custom section).

GAS would let you do `.pushsection .rodata` / `.popsection` to expand the macro correctly inside any section.  NASM has a different mechanism to allow this, which doesn't nest.  **See [the NASM manual](https://nasm.us/doc/nasmdoc7.html#section-7.3) for details** on how `section foo` also defines `__?SECT?__` as `[section foo]`, and that the "raw directive" `[section bar]` will switch without doing that.

#### Safer version that switches back to the original section

```
%macro PRINT 1
  ...
[section .rodata]        ; switch to .rodata without updating __?SECT?__
    %%str    db  %1, 0       ; arg0 + null terminator
    %%strln  equ $ - %%str   ; current position - string start
__?SECT?__               ; switch back to original section, likely [section .text]
  ... rest of the macro
```

Nesting of macros that switch sections might actually be possible by using [`%push [optional context-name] / %pop`](https://nasm.us/doc/nasmdoc4.html#section-4.7) to save/restore `__?SECT?__` on the context stack, so you can use a user-level `section` not `[section]`. But that might be incompatible with usage of macros that also `%define` things that you want visible later.  Since this is unlikely to be needed in practice, I didn't try it. (e.g. you switch to .rodata and use another macro which itself switches somewhere else.)  I mention this mostly because GAS `.pushsection` / `.popsection` does nest easily.

---

**If any of your static data is the same every time**, you can either just pull it outside the macro, or use a `%ifndef` / `%define` guard so the first use of the macro (in one file) emits the data (with a plain label not using `%%`, like `debugprint_str`) for later expansions to reference.  (See [Defining variables within a macro causes multiple definitions of the same variable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11159032/defining-variables-within-a-macro-causes-multiple-definitions-of-the-same-variab/11164557#11164557)).  On upside to that is that the data won't be part of your program at all if the macro is used zero times.  But for macro-arg strings, unless you bake the string into the symbol name, you won't be able to do duplicate elimination/folding at assemble time.

---

Also note that `equ` directives don't care what section they're in (unless they use `$` in their definition).  So `strln` needs to be in the same section as `str`, but `SYS_EXIT` has nothing to do with `section .data`.  It's an assemble-time constant that turns into an immediate when you use it that way.

---

`mov r64, imm64` is an inefficient way to put an absolute address in a register.  It needs a load-time fixup in a PIE executable, and is longer than position-independent **`lea rsi, [rel %%str]`**.  NASM assembles `mov rsi, str` into 10-byte `mov r64, imm64`, while YASM uses `mov r/m64, sign_extended_imm32` (which doesn't even work in a PIE executable).  https://nasm.us/doc/nasmdo11.html#section-11.2

You could maybe write a macro that uses `%ifidn` string-identical condition to check for `rsi` as the string arg, and in that case do nothing (the pointer is already in RSI), otherwise use `lea rsi, [rel %%str]`.  That won't work for a pointer in memory, where `mov rsi, [rbx]` would have worked, though.  Depends how fancy you want your macro to be.  You could maybe `%if` a condition that looked for `[` in the arg string and use `mov` instead of `lea`.

---

If you want to save/restore all the registers you clobber, **remember that `syscall` itself clobbers RCX (saved RIP) and R11 (saved RFLAGS).**

Normally you'd just document which registers a macro clobbers; those are all call-clobbered registers in x86-64 System V.  But if you want a debug-print macro, you probably want it to save/restore everything?  Except `push`/`pop` destroy the red-zone below RSP.

I don't think I've ever used debug-prints in asm, just setting breakpoints with a debugger and hitting "continue" to see which breakpoint is hit next.  Or just single-step and watch register values change, e.g. with GDB's `layout reg`.